# What's the radius of convergence of the next sum: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\int_o^n\frac{\sin^2t}{\sqrt[3]{t^7+1}}dt)x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

What's the radius of convergence of the next sum: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\int_0^n\frac{\sin^2t}{\sqrt[3]{t^7+1}}dt\right)x^n$$

I know that $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2t}{\sqrt[3]{t^7+1}}dt$$ does converge:

Let $$a(n)=\frac{\sin^2t}{\sqrt[3]{t^7+1}}\le \frac 1{\sqrt[3]{t^7}}=b(n),$$ $b(n)$ converges using integral test.

But now I'm stuck, How can I find that radius of convergence?

Comment: So this integral converges to some positive number. So you can apply the ratio test without difficulty.

Comment: Note that $a_n=\int_0^n {\sin^2 t\over \root3\of{t^7+1}}\,dt$, not just ${\sin^2 t\over \root3\of{t^7+1}}$. Using the comparison test, as you indicate above, you can show $\int_1^n {\sin^2 t\over \root3\of{t^7+1}}\,dt$ converges as $n$ tends to infinity. This will show that $a_n=\int_0^1 {\sin^2 t\over \root3\of{t^7+1}}\,dt+\int_1^n {\sin^2 t\over \root3\of{t^7+1}}\,dt$ converges as $n$ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n=\int_0^n {\sin^2 t\over \root 3\of{t^7+1}}\,dt$. You've noted that $(a_n)$ converges. Now note it must converge to some number $L\ne0$.  Then $(a_{n+1})$ does the same.

So, what's $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n\over a_{n+1}}$?

Comment: Amm... Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}$? if so $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1$ isn't it?

Comment: @TheAlchemist Yes; that's correct (note it's important that the limit of $(a_n)$ is non-zero here).

Comment: But in this question the limit is zero, Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{sin^2n}{\sqrt[3]{n^7+1}}=0$ So how's that helping my question?

Comment: @TheAlchemist $a_n$ is  definite integral.  It's the area under the graph of $f(t)={\sin^2 t\over\root3\of{t^7+1}} $ over the interval from from $t=0$ to $t=n$. As $n$ tends to $\infty$, $a_n=\int_0^n f(t)\,dt$ tends to a non-zero number (namely, $\int_0^\infty f(t)\,dt$).

Answer (score 1):

If $(a_n,n\geqslant 1)$ is a bounded sequence, then the radius of convergence of $\sum_na_nx^n$ is at least $1$. Here, it cannot be strictly more than $1$ since $a_n\geqslant\int_0^1\frac{\sin^2t}{\sqrt[3]{t^2+1}}dt$ for all $n$.

Comment: I don't think i fully understood what you meant. How's that Non-equality equation proves what i need?